# Measuring RAM usage of a program

Tags: process, memory, measure

`time` is a brilliant command if you want to figure out how much CPU time a given command takes.

I am looking for something similar that can measure the max RAM usage of the program and any children. Preferably it should distinguish between allocated memory that was used and unused. Maybe it could even give the median memory usage (so the memory usage you should expect when running for a long time).

So I would like to do:

```
rammeassure my_program my_args
```

and get output similar to:

```
Max memory allocated: 10233303 Bytes
Max memory used: 7233303 Bytes
Median memory allocation: 5233303 Bytes
```

I have looked at `memusg` https://gist.github.com/526585/590293d6527c91e48fcb08edb8de9fd6c88a6d82 but I regard that as somewhat a hack.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can use [tstime](https://github.com/gsauthof/tstime) to measure the highwater memory usage (RSS and virtual) of a process.

For example:

```
$ tstime date       
Tue Aug 16 21:35:02 CEST 2011

Exit status: 0

pid: 31169 (date) started: Tue Aug 16 21:35:02 2011
        real   0.017 s, user   0.000 s, sys   0.000s
        rss      888 kb, vm     9764 kb
```

It also supports a more easy to parse output mode (`-t`).

Comment: I like it. It even did The Right Thing with `./tstime -t bash -c 'perl -e "\$a=\"x\"x100000000;\$b=\$a.\$a;\$b=\"\";\$a=\"\";sleep 10;"'`

Comment: "RAM usage by the process" isn't a well-defined value: If there are several instances of the same program running, they share the executable. Most programs share `glibc` (and other assorted libraries, they are called "shared" for something). Many daemons load configuration into memory and fork(2) children, who then share the configuration data. Then there is data in readahead/writebehind buffers managed by the kernel. And then there are services that are a herd of loosely coupled processes (think of your desktop environment and all its applets and background stuff).

Comment: @vonbrand, how the Linux-Kernel computes the RSS/VSS values is well-defined.

Comment: @maxschlepzig, it may well compute some random values, that doesn't mean they mean what you think they mean: The resident set is just the pages in the process' address space that are currently in memory. That is *not* the "memory used by this process", it includes whatever it is sharing.

Comment: @vonbrand Most use cases of measuring a process's memory usage will want to measure un-shared anonymous pages, which should be very predictable with the same input.

Comment: What is *"RSS"* in this context?

Comment: @PeterMortensen it's the [resident set size](https://manpath.be/f32/procps-ng/3.3.15-7.fc32.x86_64/1/ps#L918)

Answer (score 41):

`time` is a built-in of your shell. If you like `time` but need more information, try GNU `time` in verbose (`-v`) mode:

```
/usr/bin/time -v sleep 5               
    Command being timed: "sleep 5"
    User time (seconds): 0.00
    System time (seconds): 0.00
    Percent of CPU this job got: 0%
    Elapsed (wall clock) time (h:mm:ss or m:ss): 0:05.00
    Average shared text size (kbytes): 0
    Average unshared data size (kbytes): 0
    Average stack size (kbytes): 0
    Average total size (kbytes): 0
    Maximum resident set size (kbytes): 2144
    Average resident set size (kbytes): 0
    Major (requiring I/O) page faults: 0
    Minor (reclaiming a frame) page faults: 179
    Voluntary context switches: 2
    Involuntary context switches: 1
    Swaps: 0
    File system inputs: 0
    File system outputs: 0
    Socket messages sent: 0
    Socket messages received: 0
    Signals delivered: 0
    Page size (bytes): 4096
    Exit status: 0
```

Search the package "time" or "gnutime" in your package manager.

Comment: Note that some information reported by GNU time could be inaccurate. E.g. under Ubuntu 10.04: The man page states 'The numbers are only as good as those returned  by  wait3(2)'. I.e. `wait3` fills a structure which is described in `getrusage(2)`: 'Not all fields are meaningful under Linux. [..]'.

Comment: For example on a test program that exactly allocates 10 MB (and touches each page) - GNU time reports a maxRSS of 42608 KiB - and `tstime` reports 10652 KiB. Again under Ubuntu 10.04.

Comment: I would have loved if it was this simple. On my Ubuntu machine I tried: `/usr/bin/time -v perl -e '$a="x"x100000000;$b=$a.$a;sleep 10;'`. top says it takes around 570 MB, but time says 2.3 GB. In practice that number is not usuable to me.

Comment: The factor of 4 is fixed in GNU time 1.7 and thus works as expected.

Comment: Important note: The "Maximum resident set size" only works since Linux 2.6.32.

Comment: I had to write `command time -v <program>` to get the right version of `time`. This was on Ubuntu 22.04 with bash.

Answer (score 19):

Maybe overkill, but I just found that `valgrind` has a nice tool named `massif`. I tested it on `xterm`:

```
valgrind --trace-children=yes --tool=massif xterm
ms_print massif.out.* | less
```

And you obtain a nice memory usage graph:

```
    MB
4.230^                     #                    :::::::  :::      @@:     ::: 
     |   @                 #:::@::@@:::::@::::::: :: : ::: :::::::@ ::::::: ::
     |   @               ::#:: @: @ ::: :@: :: :: :: : ::: ::: : :@ :: : :: ::
     |   @::::@@:::::::::: #:: @: @ ::: :@: :: :: :: : ::: ::: : :@ :: : :: ::
     |   @::: @ :: ::: : : #:: @: @ ::: :@: :: :: :: : ::: ::: : :@ :: : :: ::
     |   @::: @ :: ::: : : #:: @: @ ::: :@: :: :: :: : ::: ::: : :@ :: : :: ::
     |   @::: @ :: ::: : : #:: @: @ ::: :@: :: :: :: : ::: ::: : :@ :: : :: ::
     |   @::: @ :: ::: : : #:: @: @ ::: :@: :: :: :: : ::: ::: : :@ :: : :: ::
     |   @::: @ :: ::: : : #:: @: @ ::: :@: :: :: :: : ::: ::: : :@ :: : :: ::
     |   @::: @ :: ::: : : #:: @: @ ::: :@: :: :: :: : ::: ::: : :@ :: : :: ::
   0 +----------------------------------------------------------------------->Mi
     0                                                                   292.4
```

along with overly detailed memory usage info. Details in the [valgrind manual](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/ms-manual.html).

Programs will run about 20x slower though. Also, I ran some commands inside the `xterm`. Their memory footprint has been taken into account because the `--trace-children=yes` the option is there!

Comment: Th 20x speed penalty makes it unsuable for my situation. Otherwise very pretty graph!

Comment: It looks like that, at least in the version 3.8.1 of valgrind that I am using, booleans are only accepted in the form "yes/no" and not "true/false". Mine complained! :-)

Answer (score 6):

Even though the topic is quite old, I want to share another project that emerged from the cgroups Linux kernel feature.

https://github.com/gsauthof/cgmemtime:

> cgmemtime measures the high-water RSS+CACHE memory usage of a process
>   and its descendant processes.
>
> To be able to do so it puts the process into its own cgroup.
>
> For example process A allocates 10 MiB and forks a child B that
>   allocates 20 MiB and that forks a child C that allocates 30 MiB. All
>   three processes share a time window where their allocations result in
>   corresponding RSS (resident set size) memory usage.
>
> The question now is: How much memory is actually used as a result of
>   running A?
>
> Answer: 60 MiB
>
> cgmemtime is the tool to answer such questions.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like tstime doesn't work anymore under non-root under Linux >=3.0. Here's a polling utility I wrote to hack around the issue: https://github.com/jhclark/memusg/blob/master/memusg

Comment: `/usr/bin/time -v` gives the correct output in newer versions. In older versions you just need to divide by 4 to get the correct amount.

Comment: However, I don't think time -v supports peak vmemory size (only RSS). Can anyone confirm this on the latest version?