# How to know maximum memory usage of a process?

Tags: process, memory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Measuring RAM usage of a program](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18841/measuring-ram-usage-of-a-program)

I have a process, which is quite short-running (about 10 minutes), but memory heavy.

I want to know how much memory does the process uses at its peak. I want some way to track it, more efficient than running `htop` and writing down the memory usage every 20 seconds.

Ideally, I would like something like `time` - some way to write

`trackmemory command`

and the command would run and at the end, the memory usage would be shown. However, I will survive manually writing the `pid` somewhere; I just don't want to watch `htop` and writing it down.

Answer (score 2):

I found out this answer
[Measuring RAM usage of a program](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18841/measuring-ram-usage-of-a-program)

but that actually didn't work so well, because it shows me unrealistic numbers (memory 10 times higher than RAM+Swap together). What I did was

`top -bp pid > memories`

and then I filter the `memories` file using grep, sed and sort. It works quite well.