# How do I check cgroup v2 is installed on my machine?

Tags: linux, cgroups

I want to try cgroup v2 but am not sure if it is installed on my linux machine

```
>> uname -r
4.14.66-041466-generic
```

Since cgroup v2 is available in 4.12.0-rc5, I assume it should be available in the kernel version I am using.

https://www.infradead.org/~mchehab/kernel_docs/unsorted/cgroup-v2.html

However, it does not seem like my system has cgroup v2 as the memory interface files mentioned in its documentation are not available on my system.

https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cgroup-v2.txt

It seems like I still have cgroup v1.

```
/sys/fs/cgroup/memory# ls
cgroup.clone_children  memory.kmem.failcnt                 memory.kmem.tcp.usage_in_bytes   memory.memsw.usage_in_bytes      memory.swappiness
cgroup.event_control   memory.kmem.limit_in_bytes          memory.kmem.usage_in_bytes       memory.move_charge_at_immigrate  memory.usage_in_bytes
cgroup.procs           memory.kmem.max_usage_in_bytes      memory.limit_in_bytes            memory.numa_stat                 memory.use_hierarchy
cgroup.sane_behavior   memory.kmem.slabinfo                memory.max_usage_in_bytes        memory.oom_control               notify_on_release
docker                 memory.kmem.tcp.failcnt             memory.memsw.failcnt             memory.pressure_level            release_agent
memory.failcnt         memory.kmem.tcp.limit_in_bytes      memory.memsw.limit_in_bytes      memory.soft_limit_in_bytes       tasks
memory.force_empty     memory.kmem.tcp.max_usage_in_bytes  memory.memsw.max_usage_in_bytes  memory.stat
```

**Follow-up questions**
Thanks Brian for the help. Please let me know if I should be creating a new question but I think it might be helpful to other if I just ask my questions here.

1) I am unable to add cgroup controllers, following the command in the doc

```
>> echo "+cpu +memory -io" > cgroup.subtree_control
```

However, I got "echo: write error: Invalid argument". Am I missing a prerequisite to this step?

2) I ran a docker container but the docker daemon log complained about not able to find "/sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset/docker/cpuset.cpus". It seems like docker is still expecting cgroupv1. What is the best way to enable cgroupv2 support on my docker daemon?

```
docker -v
Docker version 17.09.1-ce, build aedabb7
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The easiest way is to attempt to mount the pseudo-filesystem.  If you can mount it to a location, then you can attempt to manage processes with the interface:

```
mount -t cgroup2 none $MOUNT_POINT
```

I see that you cited the documentation above.  One of the points you may be missing is that the paths still need to be created.  There's no *reason* you **must** manage cgroup resources at any particular location.  It's just convention.

For example, you could totally present `procfs` at `/usr/monkeys`... as long as the directory `/usr/monkeys` exists:

```
$ sudo mkdir /usr/monkeys
$ sudo mount -t proc none /usr/monkeys
$ ls -l /usr/monkeys
...
...
-r--r--r--.  1 root        root                      0 Sep 25 19:00 uptime
-r--r--r--.  1 root        root                      0 Sep 25 23:17 version
-r--------.  1 root        root                      0 Sep 25 23:17 vmallocinfo
-r--r--r--.  1 root        root                      0 Sep 25 18:57 vmstat
-r--r--r--.  1 root        root                      0 Sep 25 23:17 zoneinfo
$ sudo umount /usr/monkeys
```

In the same way I can do this with the cgroup v2 pseudo-filesystem:

```
$ sudo mount -t cgroup2 none /usr/monkeys
$ ls -l /usr/monkeys
total 0
-r--r--r--.  1 root root 0 Sep 23 16:58 cgroup.controllers
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root 0 Sep 23 16:58 cgroup.max.depth
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root 0 Sep 23 16:58 cgroup.max.descendants
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root 0 Sep 23 16:58 cgroup.procs
-r--r--r--.  1 root root 0 Sep 23 16:58 cgroup.stat
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root 0 Sep 23 16:58 cgroup.subtree_control
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root 0 Sep 23 16:58 cgroup.threads
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root 0 Sep 23 16:58 init.scope
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root 0 Sep 23 16:58 machine.slice
drwxr-xr-x. 59 root root 0 Sep 23 16:58 system.slice
drwxr-xr-x.  4 root root 0 Sep 23 16:58 user.slice
$ sudo umount /usr/monkeys
```

Comment: Hi Brian, thanks for the help. Wondering if you could help me with my two follow up questions. Feel free to let me know if I should be creating a new question instead.

Comment: @user3397467 You would be better off creating a separate question of the form "How do I configure Docker to use cgroupsv2?", calling out your how you're installing docker (via a distro shipped package, docker CE from their repos, etc), the distro you are running, and any configurations you may have set up to that point.

Comment: when I do this I get a weird error.

root@ip-10-0-1-179:/home/ubuntu# echo "+io" > /cgroup2/cgroup.subtree_control
bash: echo: write error: No such file or directory
root@ip-10-0-1-179:/home/ubuntu# ls -la /cgroup2/
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  6 root root 0 Feb  5 18:13 .
drwxr-xr-x  6 root root 0 Feb  5 18:13 ..
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 0 Feb  5 18:13 cg1
...
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 0 Feb  5 18:13 cgroup.subtree_control
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 0 Feb  5 18:03 init.scope
drwxr-xr-x 59 root root 0 Feb  5 17:47 system.slice
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 0 Feb  5 17:57 user.slice

Answer (score 66):

You could run the following command:

```
grep cgroup /proc/filesystems
```

If your system supports cgroupv2, you would see:

```
nodev   cgroup
nodev   cgroup2
```

On a system with only cgroupv1, you would only see:

```
nodev   cgroup
```

Comment: misuse of cat : `grep cgroup /proc/filesystems`

Comment: @kaliko thanks for your contribution. I have updated my answer to use the shortened answer you mentioned, instead of a cat + grep. Though the method remains the same, looking for cgroup and cgroup2 is key, I had tested it on 2 systems and it held true.

Comment: If you'd like a bit of informaiton, try: `mount -t cgroup2 ==> 
cgroup2 on /sys/fs/cgroup/unified type cgroup2 (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,nsdelegate)`.  If you look for a nonexistant group type, nothing happens.

Answer (score 9):

It might be not relevant not only to see if cgroups v2 are supported, but also whether they are enabled and for that following command can be used:

`stat -fc %T /sys/fs/cgroup/`

In case the output states `cgroup2fs` then cgroups v2 are used, `tmpfs` in case cgroups v1.
In case system supports cgroups v2, but not activated by default then it could be enabled by setting `systemd.unified_cgroup_hierarchy=1` as kernel parameter (eg. `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="systemd.unified_cgroup_hierarchy=1"` in systems with GRUB)

Comment: See also [how do I check if system is using cgroupv1?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/617764/86440)

Comment: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="systemd.unified_cgroup_hierarchy=1"`

Answer (score 8):

To check if your Linux system supports **cgroup v2** check for the existence of `cgroup.controllers`:

```
$ cat /sys/fs/cgroup/cgroup.controllers

cpuset cpu io memory hugetlb pids rdma
```

To boot the host with **cgroup v2**, add the following string to the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX` line in `/etc/default/grub` and then run `sudo update-grub`:

---

- `systemd.unified_cgroup_hierarchy=1`

---

- [Current Linux distros that support cgroups v2](https://rootlesscontaine.rs/getting-started/common/cgroup2/)
- [Docker 20.10 recommended for cgroups v2](https://rootlesscontaine.rs/getting-started/docker/)

---

Also helpful - [checking if you are in an unprivileged namespace](https://askubuntu.com/a/1370330/368145)

Comment: This is Docker's recommended check. First link also contains useful info on enabling cfgroup v2. Might be good to include that here, as that was would I personally was after.

Answer (score 3):

Some systems will mount cgroup v1 and cgroup v2 by default, just in different locations. It can help to see where those are with:

```
grep ^cgroup /etc/mtab
```

Example output (on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS):

```
cgroup2 /sys/fs/cgroup/unified cgroup2 rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,xattr,name=systemd 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpu,cpuacct 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/devices cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,devices 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/memory cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,memory 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,freezer 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/rdma cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,rdma 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpuset 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,blkio 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls,net_prio cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,net_cls,net_prio 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/pids cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,pids 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/hugetlb cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,hugetlb 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/perf_event cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,perf_event 0 0
```

However, this does not strictly tell you if your system *supports* cgroup v2. As the other answer mentioned, `grep cgroup /proc/filesystems` is great for that.