# how do I check if system is using cgroupv1?

Tags: cgroups

docker can only use cgroupv1, but fedora by default only use cgroupv2. How do I check if system is cgroupv1 compatible?

So far answer in [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/471476/how-do-i-check-cgroup-v2-is-installed-on-my-machine) can only determine if cgroupv2 is installed. But it cannot determine if `unified_cgroup_hierarchy` set to 0 or 1. Is there any uniform way to determine if system is cgroupv1 compatible regardless whether the cgroupv2 installed or not?

So far I use `mount -l` to check if there is `cgroup2 on /sys/fs/cgroup`. If there is, that means cgroupv2 only. Is this method universally applicable in all distros? So far I only tested on Fedora and ubuntu. If not, is there an universal way to determine this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would follow the approach used by [systemd](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/69c0807432fa4fbfbf507a53872664cd26715559/src/basic/cgroup-util.c#L1998):

- if `/sys/fs/cgroup` exists and is on a `cgroup2` file system, the system is running with a full unified hierarchy;
- if `/sys/fs/cgroup` exists and is on a `tmpfs` file system,

  - if either `/sys/fs/cgroup/unified` or `/sys/fs/cgroup/systemd` exist and are on `cgroup2` file systems, the system is using a unified hierarchy for the systemd controller only;
  - if `/sys/fs/cgroup/systemd` exists and is on a `cgroup` file system (or, as a fallback, if it exists and isn’t on a `cgroup2` file system), the system is using a legacy hierarchy.

Comment: What if /sys/fs/cgroup/unified is cgroup2 but /sys/fs/systemd is cgroup1?

Answer (score 1):

*"If `/sys/fs/cgroup/cgroup.controllers` is present on your system, you are using v2, otherwise you are using v1"*.

Source: https://rootlesscontaine.rs/getting-started/common/cgroup2/#checking-whether-cgroup-v2-is-already-enabled

Answer (score -2):

if /sys/fs/cgroup/unified is on cgroup2 and /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd/ is on cgroup , both exists with this configuration on my linux.
Then which is currently being used ?

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/422505)