# What specifies the version of cgroups (cgroups or cgroups2) used by the distro?

Tags: debian, mount, fstab, cgroups

I'm running on Debian. [When I run `mount | grep -i cgroup`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/619682/3285), I see,

```
tmpfs on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,size=4096k,nr_inodes=1024,mode=755)
cgroup2 on /sys/fs/cgroup/unified type cgroup2 (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,nsdelegate)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,xattr,name=systemd)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/pids type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,pids)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls,net_prio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,net_cls,net_prio)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/devices type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,devices)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/memory type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,memory)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,blkio)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/perf_event type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,perf_event)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/rdma type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,rdma)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpu,cpuacct)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpuset)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,freezer)
```

However my `/etc/fstab` does not have any `cgroup` or `cgroup2` mounts. Where are these mount points specified?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On systems using systemd, the cgroup mountpoints are mounted by `systemd` itself, based on [its configuration](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.html#systemd.unified_cgroup_hierarchy). If the `systemd.unified_cgroup_hierarchy` option is specified, its value (`true` or `false`) determines whether a unified cgroup v2 hierarchy is used (`true`) or a hybrid or legacy cgroup hierarchy (`false`). If no option is specified, the [compile-time default is used](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/626358/3285); if the kernel doesn’t support unified cgroup hierarchy, systemd will use the legacy hierarchy.