# How can I find what is using cgroup version 1?

Tags: cgroups

My [kernel supports `cgroup` and `cgroup2` and both of them are mounted](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/626348/3285). I'm interested in finding out if any of the applications I am running are using the legacy `cgroup` version 1? Is there anyway to determine what application has not been upgraded to use `cgroup` version 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I would like better information then this, it's an assumption that I will delete if this gets a proper answer**.

`cgroup` v2 which I know is in use on my system will not permit the unmounting,

```
$ sudo umount -f /sys/fs/cgroup/unified
umount: /sys/fs/cgroup/unified: target is busy.
```

However, the [`cgroup` v1 dirs can be unmounted just fine](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/626353/3285), regardless of [`systemd` having set them up at boot](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/626354/3285). **I assume this is because nothing is using them; I assume further that if `cgroup` v2 were not in use, they could be unmounted**.

So on the basis of not being able to unmount `cgroup` version 2, and assuming a similar behavior of `cgroup` version 1 you can determine if anything is using cgroup version 1 by simply trying ot unmount it.

Comment: You can trying `lsof` command, `sudo lsof 2>&1 | grep '/sys/fs/cgroup'`.