# How can I unmount cgroup version 1?

Tags: mount, cgroups

How can I remove cgroup version 1 mount points such that I only cgroup version 2 in my `/sys/fs/`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One easy way to do it is like this,

```
mount -t cgroup | cut -f 3 -d ' ' | xargs sudo umount
```

This will select only the mounts that are part of `cgroup` version 1, taking just their mount points and then unmounting them.

**Update:** You may also want to clean up the [remaining relics on `tmpsfs` mount at `/sys/fs/cgroup` (taken from the answer there)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/626370/3285),

```
sudo mount -o remount,rw /sys/fs/cgroup
# Delete the symlinks
sudo find /sys/fs/cgroup -maxdepth 1 -type l -exec rm {} \;
# Delete the empty directories
sudo find /sys/fs/cgroup/ -links 2 -type d -not -path '/sys/fs/cgroup/unified/*' -exec rmdir -v {} \;
sudo mount -o remount,ro /sys/fs/cgroup
```