# Creating a cgroup2 controller, getting: echo: write error: No such file or directory

Tags: cgroups

When I try to create a `pids` controller in `cgroup2`, I get

> bash: echo: write error: No such file or directory

What am I doing wrong,

```
# cd /sys/fs/cgroup/unified
# mkdir newgroup
# cd newgroup/
# echo '+pids' > cgroup.subtree_control 
bash: echo: write error: No such file or directory
```

### Basic diagnostics,

Note, for context this is after I [unmounted `cgroup` v1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/626353/3285), and [cleaned up](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/626370/3285).

```
$ mount | grep -i cgroup
tmpfs on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,size=4096k,nr_inodes=1024,mode=755)
cgroup2 on /sys/fs/cgroup/unified type cgroup2 (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,nsdelegate)
```

---

```
$ stat cgroup.subtree_control 
  File: cgroup.subtree_control
  Size: 0           Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   regular empty file
Device: 1dh/29d Inode: 1537        Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2020-12-27 18:53:19.700799276 -0600
Modify: 2020-12-27 18:53:19.696582125 -0600
Change: 2020-12-27 18:53:19.696582125 -0600
 Birth: -
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your system has enabled cgroup v1 already.
You should disable it via adding cgroup_no_v1=memory in the boot command.

Simply put,

1. $vi /etc/default/grub
2. Add "cgroup_no_v1=all systemd.unified_cgroup_hierachy=1" in GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT
3. $grub-reboot; reboot

You need to do this with sudo.