# How can I find the compile options of systemd?

Tags: systemd, cgroups

If I want to find out the compile options of `cgroup` (version 1 or version 2), such as the `systemd.unified_cgroup_hierarchy` it was compiled with, how can I find this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This information is available with `systemd --version`, at the bottom. When you run it you'll see something like

> systemd 247 (247.1-3+deb11u1)
>
> +PAM +AUDIT +SELINUX +IMA +APPARMOR +SMACK +SYSVINIT +UTMP +LIBCRYPTSETUP +GCRYPT +GNUTLS +ACL +XZ +LZ4 +ZSTD +SECCOMP +BLKID +ELFUTILS +KMOD +IDN2 -IDN +PCRE2 default-hierarchy=hybrid

The option you want here is `default-hierarchy=hybrid` ([which is set to change very soon](https://salsa.debian.org/systemd-team/systemd/-/commit/170fb124a32884bd9975ee4ea9e1ffbbc2ee26b4))