# "systemctl --version" – What does the Output mean?

Tags: systemd

```
systemctl --version

systemd 245 (245.4-4ubuntu3.15)
+PAM +AUDIT +SELINUX +IMA +APPARMOR 
+SMACK +SYSVINIT +UTMP +LIBCRYPTSETUP 
+GCRYPT +GNUTLS +ACL +XZ +LZ4 
+SECCOMP +BLKID +ELFUTILS +KMOD +IDN2 
-IDN +PCRE2 default-hierarchy=hybrid
```

1. What does `default-hierarchy=hybrid` mean?
2. What does the `+` or `-` prefixes mean? 3. And how to change them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`default-hierarchy=hybrid` means that the default cgroup hierarchy is the hybrid variant; see [What specifies the version of cgroups (cgroups or cgroups2) used by the distro?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/626348/86440) and the links there for details.

The `-` and `+` indicate systemd features; they are configured at build time. To change them, you’d have to rebuild systemd.

Comment: How to "rebuild systemd"?

Comment: @foshyboy "_Why_ to rebuild systemd" might be the real question. Generally, since systemd is a very low-level part of a Linux distro, it's not someting to take lightly. Of course, it can be an incredible learning experience, but... if that's not your goal, it might be a good idea to step back. The compiled-in options are chosen by the distro for a reason.